# How to change the Modern UI Skype to a normal window

Tags: windows-8, skype

I've installed Windows 8 and Skype from Windows Store. It now occupies the entire screen and misses a lot of features. I would say that for a normal computer, the previous "regular" Skype was much more desirable.

Should I now install one more Skype? "Metro" and "regular"? Or can I use the Modern UI Skype in a regular way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you will have to install the "regular", desktop, version of Skype if you would like to run it in desktop mode.

You can download the original installer from [here](http://www.skype.com/go/downloading).

Comment: why do I need "metro skype" on laptop? it seems useless...

Answer (score 0):

You can get the regular desktop skype from  [this link](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/get-skype/on-your-computer/windows/)