# Set Modern/Metro Apps default size

Tags: modern-ui-snapping

I tend to run the Modern/Metro apps, like Skype and Acrobat, rarely, but when I do they are fairly disruptive to my flow. They always start in full screen, and if I change to set them as left/right, they are always half the screen, disrupting other apps.

Is there a way to set a default size, like 1/3 of 1/4 of the screen?

Comment: In `Windows 8` or `Windows 8.1` this isn't possible.  Microsoft plans to fix this problem with `Windows 10`.  If you don't like applications that start in a full screen mode use the desktop versions of Skype and Adobe Acrobat instead.

Comment: Related: [How to change the Modern UI Skype to a normal window](http://superuser.com/questions/494781/how-to-change-the-modern-ui-skype-to-a-normal-window)